# Keep rhandsontable selected indicator even when there's no focus

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

rhandsontable indicates the selected cell using different shading in the row and column headers, and a border around the selected cell:

[image]

Using an example here from the first table at its [github site](http://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/).

When I click outside the table, it loses focus, and those indicators disappear:

[image]

Even though the values for the `...$select` values are unchanged.

---

**Is there a way to keep those indicators even when the table has no focus?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. `rhandsontable` is based on the JS library `handsontable`, so it's often helpful to search for options of `handsontable` instead of `rhandsontable`. Per this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/563vq3ku/) you need `outsideClickDeselects`:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

testdf <- data.frame(int = 1:10,
                     numeric = rnorm(10),
                     logical = TRUE,
                     character = LETTERS[1:10],
                     fact = factor(letters[1:10]),
                     date = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mytable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(testdf,
                  outsideClickDeselects = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```